# How could we use Service Worker to cache the content of website pages including header and footer in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, service-worker, workbox

I want to use workbox in **wordpress** site and I want to know how affectively we can use it to reduce the site speed and increase the performance.

I also want to know if there any way to cache the content of the pages? Ex some common content like header and footer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://wordpress.org/plugins/pwa/, which provides a well-supported wrapper on top of Workbox, along with reasonable defaults.

Comment: I don't want to use plugin. is there any other way?